# tar: how to exclude executables from backup?

Tags: backup, executable, tar, file-extension

I wrote a backup utility, with a file where the paths to be excluded from backup are listed.

How can I specify to exclude all executable files in a UNIX like system, where executables typically have no extension?

```
tar --create --exclude-from=exclude.txt -f backup.tar
```

I would like a standard way of doing it (Linux, Mac OS-X, BSD, ...).

Answer (score 0):

```
find dir -executable -type f > execlist.txt
tar --create --exclude-from=exclude.txt --exclude-from=execlist.txt -f backup.tar
```

Comment: I get this error (MacOS-X):  find: -executable: unknown option